# Google Hangout API integration in All platform (Android, BB, iOS and window)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-hangouts, hybrid

If I have a banking application as an hybrid application and I want to add hangout feature for audio video calling,is it possible to use or integrate hangout API in my existing application?
Required details as below- 
 •  Compatibility with Hybrid (cordova framework)
 •  Plugin/api available as open source or licenced
 •  Min and max version of Android/iOS supported
 •  Ease of integration and reviews
 •  Any issues in integration of the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. I'll address use of Hangouts API in your Banking App:

You could develop a Hangout Extension that can be accessed by your Banking App users. Your App would present a link to create a Hangout Video Call and auto-open your Hangout Extension. Your Hangout Extension would need to contact your Banking App server to notify it that there's a client waiting, and to provide the Hangout URL for your queue, or email that link to your bank rep.

[Learn more about Writing Hangouts Apps here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/writing).